# compiling error when erasing a STL std::set element by key

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stl, set

I have the following code, in which I hold a std::set of iterators to a STL container of `int`s, and erase an element by key (where the key is an iterator to the STL container). The code compiles and runs as expected (compiler is VC 2008) if the container is std::vector, but fails to compile if the container is a std::list

```
using namespace std;

typedef vector< int > Container;     //--> fails to compile if 'vector' is changed to 'list'
typedef Container::iterator IntIt;

set< IntIt > itSet;
Container c;
c.push_back (1);
c.push_back (2);
c.push_back (3);

IntIt it = c.begin ();
itSet.insert (it++);
itSet.insert (it++);
itSet.erase (c.begin ()); //--> The problematic line
```

The compile error is:

> c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio
>   9.0\VC\include\functional(143) : error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const
>   std::_Tree<_Traits> &,const
>   std::_Tree<_Traits> &)' : could not
>   deduce template argument for 'const
>   std::_Tree<_Traits> &' from 'const
>   IntIt'

So it seems to me the error is because the compiler interprets one of the template's `<` as `smaller than` operator - but I can't really understand why, or how to fix it.

Comment: It fails on VS2008, I guess it depends upon `list::iterator` implementation.

Comment: In my opinion, its really bad idea to have a `std::set` of *iterator* (of vector), because once the vector resizes itself, all the iterators in the *set* would be invalidated, and you never know when the vector resizes itself. I'm not saying that its impossible to know when it happens, but it wouldn't be elegant to have such design that requires this knowledge. If you tell us the goal as to what exactly you're trying to do, maybe we could suggest some better solutions.

Comment: What are you **really** trying to do? A set of iterators into a vector will just contain what you get when incrementing from `c.begin()` to `c.end()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact `list::iterator` does not have a comparison defined. The value type of an `std::set` requires a strict weak ordering.

A `vector` supports random access iterators, which have an ordering. A list is only required to support bidirectional iterators, which do not have an ordering (of course, an implementation is free to support random access iterators for lists as well, so on some compilers it might work).

In order to fix it, you would have to write a comparison function yourself. The problem is that the only way to detect the order of two iterators in a `list` would be to walk from one to the other, which requires linear time.

Comment: So how come it lets me push values, without a comparison operator defined?

Comment: @Itamar Katz: Does it? On VS2008 `insert` also throws an error.

Comment: Ok, it doesn't... I was too quick to ask.

Comment: Regarding your comment about writing a comparison operator - since I don't mind the order of the elements in the std::set, I can use any arbitrary comparison, not necessarily the order of two iterators (am I right..?)

Comment: @Itamar: You can use any strict weak ordering. You could for instance order by the addresses of the objects the iterator refers to. However, you might want to consider using a `boost::hash_set` from [Boost.Unordered](http://boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/unordered.html).

Comment: @Itamar - Not really, you need a proper comparison for the set to work. If you don't care about the ordering, why use a set at all?

Comment: @Bo Persson, what other container do you suggest? It is true I don't care about the ordering, but I do need to store unique elements, to be able to iterate over the elements, and to access elements (of course), and `set` gives me these functionalities.

Comment: @Itamar - Probably the example is incomplete, but just storing **all** the iterators to a vector or list is not obviously a good idea. You can just get them again when needed.

Comment: Of course I am not storing **all** iterators, sorry if it was implied in my answer/comment. All I need to store, for any given element in my container, is a few references (typically 0-5) to other elements in the container.